# Telegraf: unable to use Markdown style in reply with inlineButtons

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, telegram-bot, telegraf

The reply allowed html style with inline button but unfortunately it is not possible to use markdown style with inline button.

```
const inlineButtons = () => {
  const inlineLinks = [
    {
      title: 'Google',
      link: 'https://www.google.com/',
    },
    {
      title: 'DuckDuckGo.com',
      link: 'https://www.duckduckgo.com/',
    },
  ];

  const buttonLinks = inlineLinks.map(({ title, link }) =>
    Markup.markdown().urlButton(title, link),
  );

  return Extra.markup(m => m.inlineKeyboard(buttonLinks, { columns: 1 }));
};

// Reply message
ctx.reply(
  `<b>show_inline</b> *${show_inline}*`,
  show_inline ? inlineButtons()
);
```

With the current code there is no style with in the message
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's Extra.markdown() and Extra.HTML()

Both ctx.reply() and ctx.replyWithHTML() works, the key point is the Extra.< Something >.markup

Try not mix replyWithHTML() with Extra.markdown() // Doesn't make sense

ANS:

```
ctx.replyWithHTML(
        "<b>show_inline</b>",
        Extra.HTML().markup(m =>
            m.inlineKeyboard([
                m.callbackButton("Single", "single"),
                m.callbackButton("Range", "range")
            ])
        )
    );
```

Got my idea from https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/issues/443

Edit:
For markdown, a single _ is invalid

```
<b>show_inline\</b> *${show_inline}*
```

Use Escape \\:

```
<b>show\\_inline</b> *${show_inline}*
```

Markup doesn't have a function called markdown()
(I use TS to check the functions they have)

I don't think you can style the inline keyboard text

Comment: Sorry if you the question misled with html tags. The reason why to put `<b>show_inline</b>` is for testing purpose. The solution is looking for markdown styles for the reply with inline button https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdown-style

Comment: Apologies. Correct me if I'm wrong, you want markdown styles for the text within the **inline button**? or reply **text**?